# As I have most of the plugins in the plugin folder how do I use it in view?

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

I don't understand how to add it in config.xml without using cli.

Answer (score 0):

Open the project that you created from cli.
You can find the config.xml file there.
In config, you should specify the plugins list

`<plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="1.1.0" />`
    Refer https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/config_ref/